# When does it start to count the time limit set for password caching in `sudo`?

Tags: sudo

If I run a time-consuming command with `sudo` , after it finishes running, if I run another command with `sudo`, it seems that I don't need to type in my password again. It seems the password that I typed had been cached the whole time when the previous command is running, and is still cached for a while after the previous command finishes running.

When does it start to count the time limit set for password caching in `sudo`?

Thanks.

---

Update:

```
$ sudo sleep 14m ; sudo ls;
[sudo] password for t: 
file  file1  file2  

$ sudo sleep 15m; sudo ls;
[sudo] password for t: 
[sudo] password for t:
```

Do the above command imply that the time limit for password cache starts to count when I type in password?

Answer (score 2):

There is only **one** timeout period per user. The start timestamp of the timeout is stored inside a file. The place of the file varies by OS. Most valid actions using sudo will reset the timestamp. An action like `sudo -n` will not reset the timestamp. An action like `sudo -k` will remove the timestamp.

To check the file you need a console as root to be able to list the file at any time and a second console to start, erase and test the timestamp file.

1. Open a console, log-in to root; list the timestamp file:

   ```
   $ sudo su -
   [sudo] password for thisuser: ******
   # ls -la /var/lib/sudo/ts/thisuser
   -rw------- 1 root thisuser  240 Jul 24 07:20 thisuser
   ```
2. In the **second** console, reset the timestamp (uppercase K):

   ```
   $ sudo -K
   ```
3. Check that the file was erased using the first console.
4. Start a new sudo session

   ```
   $ sudo su -
   [sudo] password for thisuser: ******
   # ls -la /var/lib/sudo/ts/thisuser
   -rw------- 1 root thisuser  240 Jul 24 07:25 thisuser
   ```

The time in that file is the last time it was updated, probably the point at which the default timestamp timeout starts. Actually it is the timestamp that is contained inside the file, but in most cases both are the same.

---

## Docs

From man sudoers (the default timeout in minutes (`15`)). (emphasis mine)

> timestamp_timeout
> Number of minutes that can elapse before sudo will ask for a password again. The timeout may include a fractional component if minute granularity is insufficient, for example 2.5. **The default is 15**. Set this to 0 to always prompt for a password. If set to a value less than 0 the user's time stamp will not expire until the system is rebooted. This can be used to allow users to create or delete their own time stamps via sudo `-v` and sudo `-k` respectively.

Also from `man sudoers` (timestamp directory ([/var/lib/sudo/ts](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.13/sudoers.man.html) in linux [/var/run/sudo/ts](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sudoers&sektion=5) in FreeBSD and others) ) (emphasis mine):

> timestampdir
> The directory in which sudo stores its time stamp files. This directory should be cleared when the system reboots. The default is **/var/lib/sudo/ts**.

[Related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/330690/265604)
[How to read the timestamp file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332143/265604)

Answer (score 0):

This may vary by OS, but in Ubuntu your administrative privileges last for 15 minutes by default. You can modify this timeout value as described here: https://www.maketecheasier.com/change-the-sudo-password-timeout-in-ubuntu/, e.g.

Comment: I think the OP is asking “when does the timer start?” i.e. at start of command, or at end of command?

Comment: Not sure if this happens when you first execute a command as `sudo` or after the command executed as `sudo` completes.